# Out of order messages in Jboss

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, message-driven-bean

We faced an issue in the message driven bean (MDB). When multiple messages are received at the `MDB` at a same time, starting to process messages out of order. (execution sequence is not same as the receiving sequence)

eg:

Original order of the messages : `Message 1, Message 2, Message 3`

But in the application level `onMessage()` invoked in incorrect order.

eg: `Message 2, Message 1, Message 3`

We are using the `EJB3` message driven annotations in our `MDB` while `Jboss` version is `Jboss EAP 6.4` and implementation is  `HornetQ`

```
  @MessageDriven(activationConfig = { 
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
 
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "queue/Queue1"),
 
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionDurability", propertyValue = "Durable"),
 
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "reconnectAttempts", propertyValue = "-1"),
 
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "minSessions", propertyValue = "1"),
 
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSessions", propertyValue = "1"),
 
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxMessagesPerSessions", propertyValue = "1"),
 
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge")}, name = "MessageDrivenBeanEJB")
```

How can we make sure message consumption order is same as the receiving order?

Comment: Which queue are you using and how many MDBs do you have?

Comment: @Kayaman ohh sorry I should mention it.. we are using HornetQ. is it depends on how many MDBs use? we have 8 MDBs for different functionalities. Actually we don't want to bother about the order of the messages in 7 of those queues. But in other queue we have a concern about original order of receiving messages.

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect config property names for HornetQ. Try

```
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "1"),
```

You should find out which of the others that you have specified are correct for HornetQ because these look like parameters from an earlier JBoss Messaging incarnation.

Comment: Thank for the quick response. will try this configuration and update the status.Any documentation on this?

Comment: I could not find much during a quick look. You may need to refer to the HornetQ source code.